# Use multiple indexes with my FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql

I feel like I've read 20 posts on Stackoverflow about this but am still not quite sure how to answer my question.

Today I have a table called `documents` of about 10GB in size and 4 million rows. This table is a multi-tenant application so there is a column called `system_id` which segments each tenant. Today I have a query kind of like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM documents
WHERE system_id = 1 AND
      status = 100 AND
      MATCH(content,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I have two indexes created on this table:

`documents_index BTREE system_id,status`

`documents_fulltext_index FULLTEXT content,notes`

From my understanding the MySQL Optimizer is only going to run one of the indexes here and when I do `explain` I get that it will use the `FULLTEXT` index. Does this mean that the query will run a full table scan and check every row for "office" and after that, it will filter out based on `system_id` and `status`? After reading [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730) I saw that you should try to isolate the FULLTEXT because I wanted to use both the index by `system_id` and `status` and the `FULLTEXT` (is that even possible?)

```sql
SELECT B.id
    FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM documents
        WHERE system_id = 95 AND
              status = 900
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN documents B using (id)
    WHERE MATCH(content,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This significantly speeds up the query but when I do explain it shows this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: documents
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: documents_table_index
          key: documents_table_index
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 864
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: B
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: documents.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 11.11
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (1.09 sec)
```

So now it's using the `system_id` index but it doesn't look like it's using the `FULLTEXT` index on the other query because it says `PRIMARY`. Is this query not using the `FULLTEXT` index at all?

I would like to have the boolean search functionality but if I use `LIKE` instead of `FULLTEXT` it is a lot faster for a tenant that has around 10 000 records. However, if I instead try to query a tenant with for example 400 000 records on the documents table using `LIKE` then the `FULLTEXT` is faster. This is kind of explained here in the [performance analysis](https://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search).

I want it to be good for both tenants that have 10 000 documents and also 400 000 documents which should I use? `FULLTEXT` or `LIKE`? If I can get them to have the same performance I would like to use `FULLTEXT` because of the extra things you can do in boolean mode.

## UPDATE 1

Got some great answers from Rolando and Rick James below.

**I'm using InnoDB and mysql 5.7**

I have one thing that I have a hard time getting. In my case it feels like it has to be faster with the `system_id, status` index going first because out of 4 million rows it will "pluck out" the 10 000 rows that are of interest. And then you would run a `FULLTEXT` search on these 10 000 rows. However from what I've read this is not possible?

**Rolando**
I understand now that you were forcing the `FULLTEXT` index on yours and I was forcing the `system_id, status` on mine. When I flipped the query like you say it took 3.4 seconds to run the query and with forcing the `system_id, status` index it takes 0.54 seconds. Am I understanding it correctly that the `FULLTEXT` is basically a sort of TREE with all the words as tokens which means that when I'm searching for `office` it takes a longer time because there are a lot of documents with `office` in it? Compared to if I search for `ABC123` which I know is only in 1 document then it goes a lot faster.

I tried your other query as well Rolando and that took 1.3 seconds so the fastest one is still the one where I use the `system_id, status` index. At least for a word like `office`. I would like to know how that query actually works. First it's using the `system_id, status` index to just get me the 10 000 rows that are of interest. After that it's running the BOOLEAN search on each row (i.e not using an index)? This would mean that a customer (system_id) that have 400 000 documents would have a slower search than one for 10 000 documents (i.e it will scale linear with the amount of documents)? What's the difference here compared to `LIKE`? Is it that `LIKE` will look for "characters" and `FULLTEXT` will still look for words and using the boolean search functionality?

Because if I now search for `"office sverige"` instead of just `office` it takes 17 seconds with the query that forces the `system_id, status` index where as it takes 0.11 seconds to run a simple query with just `LIKE '%office sverige%'` instead.

**Rick James**
I see that you kind of answered one of my questions that `FULLTEXT` becomes slow because I bet that there are lots of documents in my database that have the word `office` in it. When I search for something that I know is very unique the query becomes faster. I do not know what my customers will be searching for exactly and I would like to not tell them that a more common word will take longer time to search for. Is this just the way it is?

The reason why I didn't go with `LIKE` is because exactly like you say. That it becomes very slow with a wildcard upfront and behind because it has to search through all possibilities. I think it's faster in this case because it's using the `system_id, status` index and that `office` is a very common word.

From the requirements that you have understood from my question could you maybe point me in the right direction for what query/solution to run? I could maybe implement something like Sphynx och ElasticSearch or other but I would really like to not do that. Right now I'm leaning towards forcing the `system_id, status` index because I think that will perform best during all different scenarios. But if I then should run `LIKE` or `MATCH` for the query? Thank you so much for your help!

## Update 2

**Rick James**
Thanks a lot for your response and I will answer your questions below:

The `status` column is probably not something to partition with. In 99% of the rows it's value will be 900. When a row is not in status 900 it means that it's being processed right now and that processing is only done once and then it becomes 900.

I'm always using `=` for `system_id` and `status`. I think that maybe I could partition based on `system_id` then because like I said this is a multi-tenant app so all of my tenants documents is in the `documents` table and then I have a key like `system_id` (should have been `tenant_id`)  that separates them.

Today there are around 4 million rows in the `documents` table but it's growing kind of fast. Say that today around 2-3000 new documents come in each day so I want to build a solution that can be viable for when there is 20 million documents for example.

Most of my tenants will have somewhere between 10-20 000 documents as a maximum but there will also be them that have 500 000 maybe. These people can accept a little bit slower search but it shouldn't be too much.

I have been thinking that one solution, although drastic, would be to not have all my tenants in the same database and have a multi-tenant app where each tenant have their own database. Then I do not have to filter by `system_id` and can instead just use the `FULLTEXT` index. This does however involve a lot of rebuilding and I would like to not have to go down that route.

Comment: If you know the number of documents a query will search, then you could decide which search type to use. We cannot tell you which would be the better for your particular case, you need to test it.

Comment: I have been thinking about that as well @Shadow but I would like to not go down that road because that means some will have the binary search functionality and some will have the `LIKE` giving different tenants different solutions. Best thing would be to use both the `system_id` index to not have to scan the full table and then the `FULLTEXT` search on that smaller result-set.

Comment: Then use a subquery to return the sysids you want and use fulltext search in the outer query.

Comment: single word searches are inefficent for full text indeces use a `LIKE`thtat will be faster for a single word

Comment: @Shadow how would that look like? I've tried this: ```SELECT id FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM documents
    WHERE system_id = 1 AND
    status = 100
) A
WHERE MATCH(content,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE);``` but that is slower than the one I showed. Alos the `explain` show that it's just using the `FULLTEXT` index. @nbk it's not always single words. That is just for show here.

Comment: The explain shows that it is using fulltext index on one subquery and the pk on the other one.

Comment: Nah the explain from what I see is using the `sysid` index for #1 and the PK for #2 and not `fulltext` anywhere. The query I showed in my last comment is a different one where I tried to "use a subquery to return the sysids you want and use fulltext search in the outer query." like you said in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` is very efficient, even for a single word.  It becomes inefficient if there are thousands of rows with the search term(s) (`'office'` in your example).

It will not be doing a "full table scan".  If you are seeing such, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` so we can dig further into it.

`LIKE` with a leading wildcard (eg, `LIKE '%office%') is very slow because it *will* do a table scan.  (Actually, in your case, ignore the search for "office" and use the other index.)

I hope the table is InnoDB, not MyISAM.  Note: the old "post" is talking about MyISAM.

The Fulltext index will be used and the other index(es) will not.

Trying to make use of both indexes (via subqueries, joins, or whatever) is unlikely to help.

**re Update 1**

If the numeric columns filter down to a fraction of a percent of the rows, that leads to a quandry.

- Doing that filtering first leads to difficulties in doing the FT filtering second.  (I don't know if it even possible.)
- Doing `LIKE '%office%'` would require checking all 10K rows.  If the 10K is sometimes 1M, this will be too costly.
- Similarly, if MATCHing 'office' leads to 1M rows, the secondary filtering is probably too costly.
- `RLIKE` provides more power, but even less speed; I see not advantage in considering it.
- `PARTITION BY` `system_id` and/or `status` *may* be viable.  What is the distribution of those columns?  If one value of either has 1M rows it won't help much when picking it.  Do you always use `=` when testing `system_id` and/or `status`?  Or maybe `IN`?  Or a range?

If the distribution is 'reasonable', here's how `PARTITION` would work.

- We would need to figure which column (system_id or status) to partition on.  This would be based on the frequency of each and how many different values there are.
- We would need to figure out how many different partitions to have -- too many would lead to a different inefficiency.
- The Optimizer would first do "partition pruning" on the "partition key" (one of those two columns).  Within that partition would be a separate `FULLTEXT` index that sees only that partition.
- I'll be more specific when I hear about the distribution of the columns.

(I do not know enough about Sphynx or ElasticSearch to comment.  A caution:  How big is the entire dataset?  How much RAM do you have?)

As for having only `INDEX(system_id, status)`, then using `LIKE` -- this might be good.  I would find extreme cases of each of the columns and run tests to see how slow or fast each query formulation is.  A dozen test cases might be easy to write and test.  I think that you will find that each query formulation (including Rolando's) will work well for some value of system_id, status, and text, and poorly for others.  The partition approach may make the worst cases less bad, while not hurting the fast cases.

FULLTEXT is faster than LIKE because FT build an inverted index of word-->row, while LIKE must scan each row each time.

**re Update2**

If `status` is almost always 900, then handle the non-900 cases differently.

Plan A:

```
SELECT *
FROM documents
WHERE system_id = 1
  AND status = 100
  AND ( content LIKE '%office%'
      OR notes LIKE '%office%' )
```

and depend on having `INDEX(system_id, status)` (either order is OK)

Plan B:

Don't index status.  Don't even search the table directly.  Instead have another table that changes a lot -- it contains *only* the records being process (status != 900).  This extra table would have only a few columns, perhaps system_id, status, and the `id` into the main table.

```
SELECT d.*
FROM ( SELECT id FROM in_progress
           WHERE system_id = 1
             AND status = 100 ) AS ip
JOIN documents AS d  ON d.id = ip.id
WHERE ( content LIKE '%office%'
      OR notes LIKE '%office%' )
```

`in_progress` might have `PRIMARY KEY(system_id, status, id)`.

Meanwhile, send any 900 requests to the main table and use MATCH.

Back to the partitioning...  How many tenants (distinct system_id values) are there?  If there are 100, you could consider separate databases.  If there are 10,000, things can get messy.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(system_id)` and try to balance them so that each partition is about the same size.  Aim for about 50 partitions when you are fully loaded.  (If `system_id` is a growing integer, you might have only a dozen portions to start with, then add more as the numbers grow.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rick James. I've posted an update now.

Comment: @Cous - I added more.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rick James. I just added an update number 2. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Plan A sounds very tempting because it would be easy to implement. This would make it slower for tenants with 409K documents compared to those with 10K though. The partioning sounds promising. I have around 100 `system_id` today and they all have very different amount of documents. Some at 400K some at 1K. Can I partition on `system_id` and then use `FULLTEXT` on this partition? That would be kind of what I want then. First use `system_id` to filter out most of the records. Then use `FULLTEXT` on the records that has been filtered. I would have one partition per `system_id`? Thanks again!

Comment: @Cous - Mostly you have the right idea.  But do not have 1 partition per system_id -- today you need 100; tomorrow you will need 1000.  Such scaling does not work well.  Instead, I suggested `BY RANGE` and aim for about 50 partitions.  To get started, you could carefully pick the ranges to (mostly) put the whales in their own partitions, while lumping the shrimp in clumps.  (Future system_ids can't be predicted; so clump them, say 20 ids per partition.  Future maintenance could shift the boundaries between partitions.)

Comment: I thank you a lot. Think that I will go with the `LIKE` version now and using the `system_id` index. There is no time to do a job with Partitioning like you say right now. I've looked at it a bit and because I'm a web-developer and not DBA this looks kind of tricky for me. If we do a rewrite in the future I will just let each system have their own database and then have a `FULLTEXT` index on this. I will give you the accept because you have been so helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cous - Sure; partitioning is not something for a non-DBA.

Answer (score 2):

You sort of have the right idea but you must isolate the fulltext search in its own subquery. In my post you read, I use this example

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (SELECT id from ft_test
WHERE MATCH(txt) AGAINST ("+cameroon" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) A
LEFT JOIN ft_test B USING (id);
```

I basically force the fulltext to be used first in the EXAPLIN plan,.

Your attempt looks like this

```
SELECT B.id
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM documents
    WHERE system_id = 95 AND
          status = 900
) A
LEFT JOIN documents B using (id)
WHERE MATCH(content,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This will force the `system_id,status` index to be used first. Query optimizer will just ignore the fulltext index and attempt doing a brute force join.

So, take your example and flip the order to use the fulltext index first

```
SELECT B.id
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM documents
    WHERE MATCH(content,notes) AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) A
LEFT JOIN documents B using (id)
WHERE B.system_id = 95 AND B.status = 900;
```

Another query pattern to try would be something like this

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM documents
    WHERE system_id = 95 AND status = 900
) A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id FROM documents
    WHERE MATCH(content,notes)
    AGAINST ('office' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) B
USING (id);
```

The MySQL Query optimizer tends to be stubborn. I have never seen a clean index merge of a fulltext index with a regular index. So, I usually recommend fulltext searches that retrieve keys only. Then, join those keys to other tables or the same table.

My approach to this is a little unorthodox but can be effective if your pattern queries coyrectly.

Sad part is, many shy away from fulltext searcing wih MySQL and switch to things like ElasticSearch (See [Elastic search full text vs mysql full text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892179/elastic-search-full-text-vs-mysql-full-text)) and [TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch) because of the frustrations of MySQL Query optimizer's treating a fulltext index like a third class citizen (Yes I said third).

Please look at the EXPLAIN Plans for these other patterns and see if it makes a difference for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RolandoMySQLDBA . I have posted an update now.

Comment: I forgot to mention: Please use `+office` instead of `office`

Comment: Thanks @RolandoMySQLDBA. I have seen that `+office` is faster but my users are not always using this. Basically they have a text field (like Google) where they can search for content in their documents.